# Drupal allow anonymous comments

Tags: drupal, drupal-comments

I'm trying to allow comments by anon users but the add comment form, "add comments" title etc is not showing. For logged in users it's showing perfectly.

I've allowed comments by anon users in the permissions page (not specific to a content type), comments are allowed for the specific node and "Anonymous posters may leave their contact information" is selected.

What could cause this? Could it be because the tpl file that shows this comment area isnt loaded somehow?

Thanks

EDIT: the problem seems to be that the contents of comment-wrapper.tpl.php isn't being loaded for anon users. This file contains a closing div that should appear below the content for all users but for anon users it's not there.

Comment: as you are referring to comment-wrapper.tpl.php, it seems to be drupal 6(?)

Comment: just to double check: do you have the "access comments" and "post comments" permissions enabled for anonymous users?

Comment: Which theme are you using, inbuilt or custom?

Comment: d'oh! access comments was not checked. many thanks

Comment: ax if you want to put that in an answer ill accept it

Comment: @stef: i just did. thank you, too :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make sure you have both the "access comments" and "post comments" permissions enabled for anonymous users.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that the old version of the page is cached. (I assume you haven't done any crazy customizations, and your site structure is straightforward.)

Try the following things:
1) Rebuild the theme registry
2) Clear the cache

These should be straightforward if you have the Devel module. Comment if not and I'll edit the post with instructions.

Comment: No change, clearing cache & theme registry is always the first thing I do :)